# Is there a fully functional Selenium WebDriver for MS Edge?

Tags: selenium, iframe, xpath, selenium-webdriver, microsoft-edge

I know this has been asked before, but there haven't been any updates on this subject recently.

So, is there a fully functional Selenium WebDriver for MS Edge? The only version I can find, which is also referenced on seleniumhq.org, is this one here, released in July 2015: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48212

I've tried it, and it has several issues:

1. inner text of web elements has leading and trailing blanks, so I can only use PartialLinkText instead of LinkText as locator
2. XPath doesn't work at all
3. switching to iFrames is not supported

It's absolutely impossible to use this version for serious testing. Are there any newer versions, betas or infos about Microsoft's work progress for the final Edge WebDriver version? Is it in progress at all?

Comment: The driver you posted is developed by MS, so it is the official driver. It is seems work in progress, MS actually provides a status of development here: https://dev.windows.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/status/webdriver/details/

Comment: I know this page. I'm just wondering that there hasn't been an updated WebDriver version since July 2015.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So that was really the solution (thank you, Martin Beeby!): If you want to use XPath locators, then you have to use the latest Microsoft Edge WebDriver (2.0 at the time of writing), even though http://seleniumhq.org still reference 1.0 on their download page. You can get it here:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49962

But if you want to use the latest driver, then you have to use the latest Edge version. But if you want to use the latest Edge version, you have to update your Windows 10 from "Build 10240" to "Version 1511" aka "Fall Update", formerly known as "Threshold 2".

You are said to get this update via WindowsUpdate, but not before you've been using your Windows 10 for at least 31 days already. Of course I cannot confirm this, as I didn't want to wait for an entire month. But Microsoft themselves say so:
http://windows.microsoft.com/de-de/windows-10/windows-update-faq

As a workaround for immediate update, you are said to be able to update manually via Microsoft's "Media Creation Tool", which I tried, but it didn't work. Instructions here:
http://www.groovypost.com/howto/install-windows-10-november-update-1511-manually-media-creation-tool/

If you're an MSDN member (like me, BTW), this version of Windows shows up as a separate product: You have one product named "Windows 10" and another product named "Windows 10, Version 1511" available for download. The latter one is the one I'm using now, and my test cases are running. Even though all of them are still red, but that's a different subject. ;-)

Comment: Nice work. Shame this info is not available on an MS page (at least that I can find)...

Answer (score 1):

They released a version from the Windows 10 fall update that can be found here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49962

Status of the WebDriver development can be found here: https://dev.windows.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/status/webdriver/details/

Comment: Sounded good at first. But then I downloaded and tried the driver. I'm using this code: `Driver = new RemoteWebDriver(url, DesiredCapabilities.Edge());`. The selenium server output is: `Exception: No such driver`, so this version seems to be even worse. Maybe that's why it isn't referenced on seleniumhq.org!? Has anyone managed to get Microsoft WebDriver 2.0 to work?

Comment: Yes, I wrote a blog post last week. I'm new to WebDriver but managed to get it compiled and working: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/thebeebs/2015/12/24/getting-started-with-webdriver/ The code I used can be seen here: https://github.com/thebeebs/Simple-Webdriver/blob/master/ConsoleApplication1/Program.cs

Comment: If you are using the fall update version of The edge Driver. Be sure you have the fall update of Windows 10 too.

Comment: I now have updated my Windows 10 with all the latest stuff from WindowsUpdate. But there was no "fall update" among them, probably because it was already installed!? My Edge version is displayed as 20.10240.16384.0. I tried with MicrosoftWebDriver 1.0, 1.1 and 2.0, but still 1.0 is the only one that gets a connection with the opened browser window at all. 1.1 and 2.0 open the browser window and then return with an exception, like before. Any other hints?

Comment: BTW, the exact exception message is: `No such driver (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 2.46 seconds
Build info: version: '2.48.2', revision: '41bccdd', time: '2015-10-09 19:59:12'
System info: host: 'E-V10-1601054', ip: '10.150.190.116', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_66'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriver`

Comment: New info: The "fall update" is not displayed in my WindowsUpdate because Windows 10 doesn't offer it unless your Windows 10 installation is more than 31 days ago, which it isn't yet in my case. I found a manual installation here: http://www.chip.de/downloads/Windows-10-Threshold-2-64-Bit_81729111.html

Comment: This update didn't work, maybe because I have Windows 10 Enterprise!? Any hints, anyone?

Comment: I too am using the Windows 10 Enterprise VM image for testing from https://dev.windows.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/vms/windows/ and I cannot get it so work.  Also have the 'No such driver' error.